# Python Selenium - Swtich calendar year -

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click on a button to change the year displayed by the calendar via the python module called Selenium.

I have tried all of the methods presented by other users but nothing seems to work. In fact, it seems to be impossible to click on a href containing some sort of Javascript code.

Have you ever encountered the same problem?

I'll join 2 pictures (Html code and UI of the calendar).

[Calendar UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlm6P.jpg)

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJp3g.jpg)

Thanks for your help/time.

Comment: Does that little calendar appear in an iframe?

Comment: That HTML should be inline in the body of the question.

Comment: I'm opening this calendar using the following command: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[img/@src="/repair/images/show-calendar.gif"]').click()

Comment: and this is the href that is called when I click on the icon to open the calendar:
<a href="javascript:show_calendar('repair_SellerSoSummaryForm', 'dateFrom');" onmouseover="window.status='Date Picker';return true;" onmouseout="window.status='';return true;"><img alt="Change Date" src="/repair/images/show-calendar.gif" class="calalign" border="0"></a>

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Rather than posting your code in a comment, edit the question and add code attempts there so they can be properly formatted and readers don't have to look through all the comments to see all the relevant info to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

From the HTML you provided, you should be able to use either link text or an XPath and click on the link/`A` tag that contains "<<"

```
find_element_by_link_text("<<")
find_element_by_xpath("//a[.='<<']")
```

Either one should work.